# CSS3 Flexbox does not extend its width on iOS with overflow-scroll

Tags: ios, css, webkit, ionic-framework

I am programming a simple movieDB app with Ionic. A part of it is listing actors, who play in a movie as a scrollable vertical card list. I am using good ol' divs and custom CSS.

This is how it looks like in a browser (Firefox 38 on Mac): this is the DESIRED behavior

[image: Desired behavior]

however when I emulate it on iOS (iOS 7.1.1 on iPad) I get this:

[image: Funny iOS behavior]

It is scrollable, but the divs overlap. They are collapsed.

You can find my CSS code below. I believe that I have tried a combination of every -webkit tag out there and I still can't get it to work.

Any help greatly appreciated :)

```
#actorsBox{
display: flex;
display: -webkit-flex;

flex-direction: row;

-webkit-justify-content: space-between;

overflow-y: scroll;
-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;

align-items: center;

#actor {
  height: 30vh;
  width: 15vw;

  margin-left: 2vw;
  padding-top: 12vh;
  border-radius: 5px;

  text-align: center;

  background-color: cornflowerblue;
}}
```

**UPDATE 7:45 GMT 25.6.2015**

Thanks to [COOOL](https://stackoverflow.com/users/973397/coool)'s answer I am able to track the origin of this behavior, so I am updating the question:

In browsers, `overflow-scroll` extends the flexbox to accomodate all items with their original widths. However with the current code, iOS just squeezes them all in the original dimensions of the flexbox. If I were to put anything more than 100px they would overlap again (see the code below).

[image: squeezed elements]

```
#actorsBox{

display: flex;
display: -webkit-flex;

flex-direction: row;

-webkit-justify-content: space-between;

overflow-y: scroll;
overflow-scrolling: auto;
-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;

align-items: center;

.actor {
  height: 30vh;
  width: 100px;
  min-width: 100px;
```

However if I set width of #actorsBox to something big (say 2000px) the items are spaced out nicely again.

It seems to me that `-webkit-overflow-scrolling` is the cause of the issue. Does anyone have some experience with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Well, firstly your using a div* `#id` *for an area you should be using a* `.class`

*a* `.class` *is for selecting multiple instances as an* `#id` *is for one unique instance.*

---

It looks like you have `#actor` as the selector of the problematic content. And it looks like your `width` is being ignored.

You can firstly try using `px` or `%` (instead of `vw`) where you have this:   `width: 15vw;`
Or define a `min-width` for the actor boxes.

```
.actor { // firstly change to a class
  height: 30vh;
  width: 15vw; // mobile browser could dislike this, if below doesn't work try using % or px
  min-width: 20px; // or whatever is relevant, may require some testing
  /// the rest of your cool styles
  }
```

---

**Update**: (re: your comment)

If `2000px` on `#actorsBox` responded well, then you may need to add a `min-width` there as well. (or at-least define a width)

```
    #actorsBox{
    // all your previous styles
    width: 1000px; // hows it gonna know when to overflow, bro?
    overflow-y: scroll;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
    // I would add min-width in px then width 100% and a max-width in px
    // but declaring a width here is all you need
    align-items: center;
    }
```

*In any case you need a width defined where you have an* [overflow-scroll](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp) *defined*. This is likely your issue; if the above still doesn't work try also adding this position:relative; to assure `.actor` is relative to this as a wrapper

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It didn't solve the issue, but it got me closer. I've updated the question, could you please look at it again? Thanks.

Comment: @JanoHorvah check it out now; your close your just missing a few elements

Comment: If you add your full code, I can create a jsfiddle for you

Comment: the width was inherited from the parent div. so it makes no difference to set it manually. Lets just leave it here - I will be offline for a while now so I won't be able to solve it. If you really want to finish this, create a horizontal flex-box with multiple elements via ng-repeat and try to `ionic emulate` it. If you manage to get a working demo please share, that would be great :) thanks for the effort man!